# Snakemake using checkpoint to end workflow

Tags: snakemake

This question is related to my previous post [Snakemake exit a rule during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468895/snakemake-exit-a-rule-during-execution?noredirect=1#comment114012170_64468895). Basically for my workflow it's possible that an empty file will be produced in one of the rules, and I want to exit the workflow with a helpful message. Someone suggested to use the checkpoint function, and here's what I have:

```
def readFile(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        line = f.readline()
        return(line.strip())

def isFileEmpty():
        with checkpoints.step1.output[0].open() as f:
                line = f.readline()
                if line.strip() != '':
                        return "output/final.txt"
                else:
                        return "out.txt"

rule all:
    input: isFileEmpty()

checkpoint step1:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: "out.txt"
    run:
        if readFile(input[0]) == 'a':
            shell("echo 'a' > out.txt")
        else:
            shell("echo '' > out.txt")
            print("Out.txt is empty")

rule step2:
    input: "out.txt"
    output: "output/out2.txt"
    run:
        shell("echo 'out2' > output/out2.txt")
            

rule step3:
    input: "output/out2.txt"
    output: "output/final.txt"
    run: shell("echo 'final' > output/final.txt")
```

In checkpoint step 1, I'm reading the file contents of input.txt and if doesn't contain the letter 'a' then an empty out.txt will be produced. If out.txt is not empty, step2 and 3 will be performed to give output/out2.txt and output/final.txt at the end. If it's empty, the workflow should end at checkpoint step 1 with only out.txt produced. Right now when I run the workflow is giving me this error:

```
AttributeError in line 7 of Snakefile:
'Checkpoints' object has no attribute 'step1'
```

Is my syntax of checkpoints.step1.output[0].open() wrong? In the checkpoints documentation it's written as checkpoints.somestep.get(sample=wildcards.sample).output[0] but I don't have any wildcards in my snakemake output. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, turns out just some minor modifications of syntaxes:

```
def readFile(file):
        with open(file) as f:
                line = f.readline()
                return(line.strip())

def isFileEmpty(wildcards):
        with checkpoints.step1.get(**wildcards).output[0].open() as f:
                line = f.readline()
                if line.strip() != '':
                        return "output/final.txt"
                else:
                        return "out.txt"

rule all:
        input: isFileEmpty

checkpoint step1:
        input: "input.txt"
        output: "out.txt"
        run:
                if readFile(input[0]) == 'a':
                        shell("echo 'a' > out.txt")
                else:
                        shell("echo '' > out.txt")
                        print("Out.txt is empty")

rule step2:
        input: "out.txt"
        output: "output/out2.txt"
        run:
                shell("echo 'out2' > output/out2.txt")


rule step3:
        input: "output/out2.txt"
        output: "output/final.txt"
        run: shell("echo 'final' > output/final.txt")
```